# Should I load HTML WebComponents from a remote, untrusted URL?

Tags: html, web-component, shadow-dom, web-standards

Material on [WebComponents](https://www.webcomponents.org/introduction) and HTML Imports seems to be scarce, so I can't find a definite answer on this.

All the examples of importing a WebComponent seem to do so through local URLs. What I'm wondering is, is there a way to load WebComponents from remote URLs in a secure way? The use-case for this would be the user would be able to enter a WebComponent URL, and my application would display this component.

I wouldn't want a remote WebComponent to be able to access the host's localStorage, which may contain sensitive data. I've read about the [ShadowDOM](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/getting-started/primers/shadowdom#support), but I'm still not sure if this protects things like localStorage/sessionStorage.

Comment: yes you can do that

Comment: The question is not can, but _should_.

Comment: Sorry: No you should not do that :-) shadow dom won't help either. Afaik security rules and risks are the same for HTML imports and XMLHttpRequest/fetch.